# Visa to Puerto Rico

Tags: visas, puerto-rico, kenyan-citizens

I am a Kenyan citizen, planning to visit Puerto Rico soon.  How easy is it to get a PR visa?  How much will it cost?  And what is the longest period I can be allowed to stay on a tourist visa?

Comment: The website of the [Puerto Rican embassy in Nairobi](http://embassynairobi.com/puerto-rican/) should contain all the information you need. It is always better to get this kind of information from official sources, rather than relying on random people on the internet to get it right. Of course, we try our hardest but mistakes can happen.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The *Puerto Rican embassy"!?  I think you meant the U.S. Embassy: https://ke.usembassy.gov/

Comment: @jpatokal Ha! Of course you're right, which pretty much proves my point about not relying on random people on the internet ot get it right. (I guess I confused Puerto Rico and Costa Rica and didn't check the link very well.)

Answer (score 4):

Puerto Rico is a part in of the United States, so **visa requirements are exactly the same visiting mainland USA**.

Comment: @BerniceWanguiGetata Happy to help.  Please accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark if it answered your question.